# Proper backend structure for a group message application

Tags: mysql, ios, sql

favorite
If I'm designing the backend for a messaging app that allows group texts and has the following structure:

Message Table

```
message id | creator | message data | date created
```

Conversation Table

```
conversation id | creator | date created
```

ConversationtoMessage Table

```
conversationtomessage id | conversation id | message id
```

ConversationtoUser Table

```
conversationtouser id | conversation id | user id
```

Does it makes sense to have the creator of the conversation column in the conversation table, or is that redundant information given that the creator will also be linked in the conversationtouser table

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done using two tables only:

users

1. id (unique id)
2. username
3. name
4. created

messages

1. id (unique id)
2. user_id
3. type (1 for individual messages, 2 for group messages)
4. message_identifier ( unique id for particular conversation)
5. message_text
6. created